# RoutedEvent "Loaded" is not called when Listboxitem is added after updating XML Itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox in WPF which is binded using an XMLDataProvider which points to an xml File.

I have a storyboard set in the itemtemplate of my ListBoxItem as such:

```
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:.2" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" From="0" Duration="0:0:.2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

This works great when the file is first loaded on starting the application. However when I add a new XMl element to the list like this:

```
MainNode.AppendChild(NewElement)
```

The element is added to the list but the storyboard does not fire. How can I make sure the programatically added item calls the "Loaded" event onto itself?

UPDATE: The style was applied to ListBox instead of ListBoxItem. Changing solved the question.

Comment: `Style` is applied on `ListBox` or `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: ListBox it seemed. I rest my case and will update my question. Thanks

Comment: `ListBox` loaded event will be raised only when it gets loaded on UI first time and not afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `Style` should be applied on `ListBoxItem` which will be raised for every new ListBoxItem add.

`ListBox` loaded event will be raised only when it gets loaded on UI first time and not afterwards. So, move the style from ListBox to ListBoxItem.